# PHP Variable from extended class

Tags: php, class, variables, extends

I'm trying to retrieve a variable from an extended class. This is how my main class looks:

```
class SS {
    public $NONE = NULL;
    public $NUMBERS = array("1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "0");
    public $OPERATORS = array("=", "&&", ">", "<", "+", "-", "/", "*", "^");
    public $DBLQUOTES = '"$1"';
    public $SNGQUOTES = "'$1'";
    public $CODE;

    function SuperSyn($sCode, $cLang) {         
        $hLang = new VB6;
        $VB6 = $hLang->__construct();
        echo $VB6->ssAuthor;
    }
}
```

And my extended class looks like this (I've removed many of the keywords).

```
class VB6 extends SS {
    public function __construct() {
        $ssAuthor = "James Brooks";
        $ssCSS = "languages/vb6.css";
        $ssNumbers = $NUMBERS;
        $ssKeywords = array("Abs", "Access", "AddItem");
        $ssReserved = $NONE;
        $ssComments = "('.+)";
        $ssOperators = $OPERATORS;
        $ssDoubleQuote = $NONE;
        $ssSingleQuote = $NONE;
    }
}
```

If I remove the public function __construct being called, PHP bitches that it's expecting a function.

My question is, how can I retrieve a variable from the extended class into my main class?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The constructor will be called for you when you create an object, so this should work:

```
function SuperSyn($sCode, $cLang) {                     
     $hLang = new VB6(); //I think you need some parameters here
     echo $VhLang->ssAuthor;
}
```

However in your VB6 constructor you are currently only assigning local variables, so you wouldn't be able to access ssAuthor externally. Instead you probably want to do something like:

```
class VB6 extends SS {
    public $ssAuthor;

    public function __construct() {
        $this->ssAuthor = "James Brooks";
        //etc.
    }
}
```

Comment: That's brilliant! Thank you Tom!

Answer (score 1):

Use php's parent keyword.

[PHP parent](http://us.php.net/manual/en/keyword.parent.php)

Comment: Where though? Where am I putting the keyword?

Comment: Check:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/393204/using-parent-variables-in-a-extended-class-in-php

There the topic is discussed in detail.

Answer (score 0):

I think that there's a logical problem with your expectiation. Why should a function of the class SS know about a variable that only exists in the VB6 subclass?

That would not be a clean inheritance behaviour and reveals a problem with your classes.

Two choices to solve that:

- Put the variable in the main class to use it in a function in that class
- Put the function using the subclass's variable inside the subclass

(After reading the comments about the parent keyword and ´$this´ variable: I understood the question differently and don't think either of those to would help since the opposite direction is required: parent class function > subclass variable, not subclass function > parent class variable)

Comment: Well the idea of this is that you'll be able to create your own classes for different languages, I need to be able to get each of the different syntax rules from the class.

Comment: If you'll have to fetch individual information from the subclasses it might be a good idea to make the SS class abstract and add an abstract function like ´getSyntaxRules()´ that each subclass has to implement and that returns the rules for that language.

Answer (score 0):

use `parent::` or `$this->` (depends, i.e. you have two variables with the same name)

Comment: But where? If I've still got the function in the extended class, where?

Comment: wait. after reading your code again it doesn’t make sense at all. you hold an derived object in the base class? (SS:SuperSyn that is) and why do you re-apply all your member variables? nevertheless, this should work: `$ssNumbers = $this->NUMBERS`